# How to build SDL2 during project build using cmake?

Tags: c++, cmake, sdl-2

I want to make myself a cross-platform setup for graphics. I am trying to build SDL2 using cmake. Here is my current CMakeLists.txt :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.0 FATAL_ERROR)

set(PROJECT_NAME "OpenGLZero")
set(SDL2_DIR "external/SDL2-2.0.9")
set(GLEW_SOURCE_DIR "external/glew-2.1.0")
set(GLM_SOURCE_DIR "external/glm-0.9.9.3")
set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS OFF CACHE BOOL "")
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
add_subdirectory(${SDL2_DIR})
include_directories(${GLEW_SOURCE_DIR}/include
                    ${GLM_SOURCE_DIR}
                    ${SDL2_DIR}/include)
# building glew as a static library
add_library(glew STATIC
    ${GLEW_SOURCE_DIR}/src/glew.c
    ${GLEW_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
add_definitions(-DGLEW_STATIC)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} SDL2main SDL2 ${OPENGL_LIBRARY} glew)
```

It is not able to find `SDL2.dll` file on windows (present in `build\external\SDL2-2.0.9\Release\`), although I am linking the libraries. Linking using `${SDL2_LIBRARIES}` doesn't work here, probably because I am not using `find_package` which includes all the paths. I am not using `find_package` because I want to build SDL2 from scratch instead of passing binaries for Windows and Mac and installing SDL2 in linux using apt. What should I do to allow a generic method for finding SDL2 libs without having to provide binaries?

Comment: When build other library with `add_subdirectory` approach, it is preferred to link with a library **target**, not a file. If  you look into SDL2's [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/SDL-mirror/SDL/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L1771), then you will find that name of the **static** library target is `SDL2-static`, so you need to link with it instead of `SDL2`.

Comment: Thank you, that worked for me.

Comment: Just as a frame challenge: Especially on Linux (you mentioned you wanted it to be cross platform), a lot of people will object to being forced to use your embedded copy of SDL2.  (For example: Then they're held hostage to your release schedule in updating SDL2 to fix security vulnerabilities.)  What we do here is to provide customers with repositories of packages, e.g. Chocolatey / NuGet packages for Windows, .deb packages for Debian/Ubuntu, .rpm packages for CentOS, which are installed using the system's package manager (but not into system directories) and then use those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When build other library with `add_subdirectory` approach, it is preferred to link with a library **target**, not a *file*.

If you look into SDL2's [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/SDL-mirror/SDL/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L1771), then you will find that name of the **static** library target is `SDL2-static`, so you need to link with it instead of `SDL2`.

---

Would you use `find_package()` approach (with pre-installed binaries), the name of the static SDL2 library target would be `SDL2::SDL2-static` (prefix `XXX::` means that the target is an *IMPORTED* one).